# Model Overlapping

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two models and two buttons. Each button triggers 1 model, and the buttons hidden. I want to trigger the functions using `jQuery`, like `$('#appbutton').click()`.

When triggering `appmodel`, `dbmodel` is also trigged and they overlap one another.

```html
<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#appmodel" hidden="hidden" id="appbutton">Extra large modal</button>
<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dbmodel" hidden="hidden" dbbutton">Extra large modal</button>

<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-xl" role="dialog" id="appmodel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <h4 class="display-4">APP Display</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" role="dialog" id="dbmodel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <h4 class="display-4">DB Display</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 1):

I removed hidden and `data-target` from `html` so buttons can be visible. and we can try writing click operation on Button to `show modal` via `javascript`.

**HTML**

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="modal"   id="appbutton">Extra large modal</button>
<button type="button" data-toggle="modal"  id="dbbutton">Extra large modal</button>

<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-xl" role="dialog" id="appmodel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <h4 class="display-4">APP Display</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" role="dialog" id="dbmodel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <h4 class="display-4">DB Display</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$("#appbutton").click(function(){
    $("#appmodel").modal('show')
})
$("#dbbutton").click(function(){
    $("#dbmodel").modal('show')
})
```

Here is test for it https://jsfiddle.net/cb1asyne/

Now you can hide your buttons and apply a click trigger on buttons like

```
Based on some operation trigger Below
$("appbutton").trigger("click")
$("dbbutton").trigger("click")
```

Hope this will help you, let me know for more clarification.

Comment: when i use .modal('show') model is not loading properly it blink one time and get hidden

Comment: @Vijay could you try on jsfiddle and share

Answer (score 0):

You can toggle visibility of either one using the following code:

```js
const appModel = document.getElementById("appmodel");
const dbModel = document.getElementById("dbmodel");

function setAppModelVisible() {
  appModel.style.visibility = "visible";
  dbModel.style.visibility = "hidden";
}

function setDbModelVisible() {
 dbModel.style.visibility = "visible";
 appModel.style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

```html
<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#appmodel"  id="appbutton" onclick="setAppModelVisible()">Extra large modal</button>
<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dbmodel" id="dbbutton" onclick="setDbModelVisible()">Extra large modal</button>

<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-xl" role="dialog" id="appmodel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <h4 class="display-4">APP Display</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" role="dialog" id="dbmodel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <h4 class="display-4">DB Display</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```